# Activity of Device is not detecting in Android using Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I have tried to get device activity such as device is traveling in Vehicle, bicycle, walking or running or not travelling using google play service library but ActivityRecognitionResult getting as null.

Tried out code is in Class1.java:-

```
public class Class1 extends BroadcastReceiver
{
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
public static String ACTION_STRING= "action";
Intent intentp = new Intent(context, Class2.class);
intentp.setAction(ACTION_STRING);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentp, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
}
}
```

And code in Class2.java:-

```
public class Class2 extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {
        if(intent.getAction() == Alarm.ACTION_STRING)
        {
            if(ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent))   //Here condition getting as false
            {
                ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
                DetectedActivity detectedActivity = result.getMostProbableActivity();
                int activityType = detectedActivity.getType();
                if(activityType != DetectedActivity.STILL)
                {
                                 //Here doing something;
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

How to detect activity of device using Google Play Services?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionClient):

> Use of the ActivityRecognitionClient requires the com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission.

It the permission properly requested by your app?